# Structure hyperlinks relating to multiple articles

Tags: html

I have a simple HTML5 structure that includes multiple `<article>` tags. Each article is further divided into `<section>` tags. I would like to specify the sources (hyperlinks) for all the articles at the end. However, I am unsure on how to structure them correctly (according to HTML5 standards), so that they structurally relate to the articles that were discussed.

```
<article>
    <section class="introduction">
    </section>
    <section class="experiment">
    </section>
    <section class="conclusion">
    </section>
</article>

<article>
    <section class="introduction">
    </section>
    <section class="experiment">
    </section>
    <section class="conclusion">
    </section>
</article>

<!-- How do I structure the sources?
<ul>
    <li><a>Link to source</a></li>
    <li><a>Link to source</a></li>
    <li><a>Link to source</a></li>
</ul>
-->
```

My question is: *how do I structure my sources (hyperlinks) so that they correctly belong to the articles that came before?*

Edit: I am basically asking if it is correct HTML5 to just leave the `<ul>` as it is, without any surrounding tags?

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href="#introduction"</a></li>
<li><a href="#experiment"</a></li>
<li><a href="#conclusion"</a></li>
```

Comment: Don't just blurt out code! Adding some text to describe how this best answers the question will improve the long-term value of the answer and help to prevent it from being deleted during review.

Answer (score 0):

It is best you use an **"id"** instead of a class for each of the section element.
Making reference to the articles discussed, you can use the "id" name as the value of the **"href"** attribute.
See this:

```html
<article>
    <section id="introduction">
    </section>
    <section id="experiment">
    </section>
    <section id="conclusion">
    </section>
</article>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#introduction">Link to source</a></li>
    <li><a href="#experiment">Link to source</a></li>
    <li><a href="#conclusion">Link to source</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is it correct HTML5 to just leave the `<ul>` tag like this? This is essentially my question: _should you not wrap the_ `<ul>` _in another tag to signify that it belongs to the articles that came before?_